# Ipython Notebooks missing

Tags: storage, ipython

After the most recent windows update (I downloaded about an hour ago), I can no longer locate my Ipython Notebooks. I run the Ipython Notebook as administrator since these wouldn't print properly otherwise, and this would show and save notebooks from/on a different location from the default (the default location being the one wherein I don't have to run as administrator). With this most recent update, the ran-as-administrator notebooks no longer show up, and I also can't locate them in my hard drive. I tried a system restore but this didn't help. I'm using Python 2.7 with Windows 7 professional on a Thinkpad T520.

I want to know where I can find the missing notebooks. These don't know show up in the Ipython Notebook home page, and also when I search the system for .ipynb files.

Answer (score 0):

I found the files. These were in the System32 folder.